# Unsupported operand type(s) in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and am having trouble with functions/defining something properly.
Now I am getting the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

I have to output it a certain way and meet specific directions given to me, but I just can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will include an image of the rules I have to follow, I figured out how to make it work when not following the rules but can't make it work when I try to stick to them.
[Direction to follow for coding this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lozR.png)

```
# A function that prompts the user for a name and returns it to the
# calling statement.
def getName():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return name

# A function that prompts the user for a score and returns it to the
# calling statement. 
def score_input():
    int(input("Enter your score: "))
    
# A function that receives two numbers and returns the average of those
# two values to the calling statement.
def find_avg():
    (score_a + score_b) / 2
    
# A function that receives a string and a number (the name and the
# average score) and prints it out on the screen in the appropriate format.
def output():
    print("Hi, {}. Your average score is {}".format(name, avg))

#############################################################################

# prompt for name
name = getName()

# prompt for two scores
score_a = score_input()
score_b = score_input()

# calculate the average
avg = find_avg()

# display the final output
output()
```

Comment: In which line does this error occur?  please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just like you return the value of the user's name in getName, you should be returning the values processed in score_input() and find_avg().  Since they currently return nothing, Python treats the values assigned with each function as "None."

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
You obviously expected that those variables have normal values, rather than `None`.  Where do *you* think they get those values?  How did they get to be `None`?  You should trace this before you post here.

Comment: All functions except getName do not return anything, aka they return None.

Comment: General rule of thumb when you see a `NoneType` error: look for the function that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

`score_input` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`.

Comment: `find_avg` has the same problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, but `score_input` is causing the error cited.

Answer (score 1):

Two of your functions neglect to return the computed values, so they return `None` by default. Just change them to:

```
def score_input():
    return int(input("Enter your score: "))
  # ^^^^^^ added return

def find_avg():
    return (score_a + score_b) / 2
  # ^^^^^^ added return
```

and you won't get `None`s when you call them.

Side-note: It's typically considered bad form to rely on non-constant globals. I'd suggest changing `output` to be more reusable by having it receive the items to output as arguments, e.g.:

```
def output(name, avg):
    print("Hi, {}. Your average score is {}".format(name, avg))
```

then calling it with:

```
output(name, avg)
```

Same goes for `find_avg`. Packaging the script functionality up into a `main` method helps avoid accidentally relying on globals, which would get final code like this (comments omitted for brevity):

```
def getName():
    return input("Please enter your name: ")

def score_input():
    return int(input("Enter your score: "))
    
def find_avg(a, b):
    return (a + b) / 2
    
def output(name, avg):
    print("Hi, {}. Your average score is {}".format(name, avg))

#############################################################################

# Wrapping script functionality in main ensures all variables are local,
# not global, which ensures you don't accidentally depend on global state
def main():
    name = getName()
    
    score_a = score_input()
    score_b = score_input()
    
    avg = find_avg(score_a, score_b)
    
    output(name, avg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # Called only when invoked as a script, not when imported as a module
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return the input from the function `score_input`. So the return type is `None`.

In order to make your code work you would need to add `return {expression}` in the function.

This is how I would change the code:

```
# A function that prompts the user for a name and returns it to the
# calling statement.
def getName():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return name

# A function that prompts the user for a score and returns it to the
# calling statement. 
def score_input():
    return int(input("Enter your score: "))
    
# A function that receives two numbers and returns the average of those
# two values to the calling statement.
def find_avg():
    return (score_a + score_b) / 2
    
# A function that receives a string and a number (the name and the
# average score) and prints it out on the screen in the appropriate format.
def output():
    print("Hi, {}. Your average score is {}".format(name, avg))

#############################################################################

# prompt for name
name = getName()

# prompt for two scores
score_a = score_input()
score_b = score_input()

# calculate the average
avg = find_avg()

# display the final output
output()
```